# Accessing variable from main Vue.js instance in component VM

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-resource

Here's a very simple Vue app that is passing a prop from the main VM to a component. This value is grabbed via vue-resource in my actual application.

https://jsbin.com/tazuyupigi/1/edit?html,output

Of course it works, but I'm struggling to access this value from the component VM itself.

https://jsbin.com/hurulavoko/1/edit?html,output

As you can see, my alert shows undefined. How can I fix this? Seems to be an issue with order of execution, but using `compiled()` or `created()` in place of `ready()` makes no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a problem with order of execution.  The main Vue instance isn't "ready" until the things inside it have been compiled.  This includes the `hello` component.

If you need to know that `bar` has been set before you use it, you can monitor for that in a couple of ways.  You could `$broadcast` an event in the parent to let the child know that `bar` has been loaded.  Or you could use a `watch` function in the child component to make changes when `bar` is updated.

Your example does work if you `$set` `bar` in `created()`, however with `vue-resource` you're going to have a delay anyway, so you need to account for the fact that `greeting` won't be ready during the child's `ready()` function.  You'll either have to design your DOM structure to handle the fact that `greeting` could be `undefined`, or you'll have to use an event or `watch` function to wait for it yourself.

Example with `$broadcast`:

```
Vue.component('hello', {
  template: 'From hello tag: {{ greeting }}',
  props: ['greeting'],
  ready: function() {

  },
  events:{
    'bar-ready':function(){
        alert(this.greeting)
    }
  }
});
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    created: function() {
        this.$http.get('/path')
            .then(function(response){
                this.$set('bar',response.data);
                this.$broadcast('bar-ready')
            }.bind(this))
    }
});
```

`$broadcast` docs: https://vuejs.org/api/#vm-broadcast

Comment: Disregard the previous comment, it was just a typo on my part. The broadcast system got everything working for me. Thanks!